Forward-declaration of std::vector element type for function parameters
The following compiles (on GCC) as long as B is fully known (and actually used) where A::foo() is defined.
#include <vector>

class B;

struct A
{
    void foo(const std::vector<B>& bees);
};

Is this defined behavior as far as C++ standard is concerned and an acceptable forward-declaration usage?

References to incomplete types

We can have references and pointers to incomplete types. For example, you could even write void foo(const B& b);. Until you odr-use the incomplete type, a definition isn't strictly required.

@user12002570 the uncertainty was around the complete type needed for the stl template instantiation.

All you have is a function declaration in the shown code. To begin with, the types of function parameters are not required to be complete in a declaration that isn't a definition.
Even in the definition the fact that const std::vector<B>& needs to be a complete type doesn't imply that std::vector<B> needs to be complete either. A reference to an incomplete type is still complete. It is required to be complete only if e.g. member lookup is performed on bees in the function definition.
So, because std::vector<B> isn't required to be complete, it isn't implicitly instantiated. Because it isn't implicitly instantiated it can't matter whether or not std::vector allows incomplete types as template argument.
And even if it did matter, since C++17 std::vector is permitted to be instantiated with an incomplete type as argument as long as no members of the vector are used before the type is completed.

Note, in case you are not aware: A class type is complete if it has been defined and incomplete if it has only been forward-declared.
